# Is there a copy of the main MBR and MFT on a drive?

Tags: hard-drive, mbr, mft

I'm talking about something like a backup copy located on a drive, in addition to the main.

If there is, how would I be able to retrieve it and write the backup back to the main partition?

Comment: [Test Disk can do this](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) but is not for the inexperienced, lots of reading to do before use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MBR partition table does not have a backup, but some tools can try to discover old partition locations by scanning the whole drive.

(A GPT partition table *does* have a copy; the backup GPT header is on the very last sector of a disk, while the partition entries precede it. On Linux, `gdisk` aka gptfdisk can restore the backup to main GPT. Many recent computers in fact use GPT+UEFI, rather than MBR+BIOS.)

The MFT "master file table" is a *filesystem* concept, so it is per-partition and depends on which filesystem each partition uses. For example, NTFS does have a backup copy, which TestDisk can restore files from.

Comment: I believe NTFS is the only file system that actually uses the term *MFT or Master File Table*. Other file systems of course have data structures that serve a similar purpose, but they call them by other names.

Comment: 'FAT' is actually short for 'File Allocation Table', with the "filesystem" implied from this. The table keeps track of where files are stored - which should be about the same as what a 'MFT' is used for.

Comment: @grawity, does that mean I can't use any MBR backup to replace a corrupt MBR or correct one? There's a long running issue I'm having, you can join the discussion and share your insight: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29827/discussion-on-question-by-xcare-recovering-files-when-windows-7-mbr-has-been-cor

Comment: @grawity, your answer only answers a portion of my question, please indicate the software and steps to write an MBR back to an HDD.

Comment: There is no MFT copy in NTFS. There is a thing called MFT mirror but it only contains a few important entries from the MFT.